# Add support for new html tag

Tags: browser, tags, browser-plugin

The major browsers have support for the `<object/>` tag.

I want to incorporate a video player on my site to play .mkv video, but I cannot use most because the are based on flash, which can only play .flv & .f4v.

That's why I'm switching to the `<object/>` tag

But, if I wanted to incorporate a tag with the name of `<mkvvideo/>`, would a simple plugin associated with that tag be usable, or does the core programming of the browser handle that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't associate plugins with tags.
Instead you [register the mimetypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Development_Overview#Registering_Plug-ins) (and file extensions) that your plugin supports and use that mimetype with the object tag (in this case `video/x-matroska`).